# Under which conditions is the AbortSignal in the TanStack useQuery function undefined?

Tags: typescript, fetch-api, react-query

The documentation of TanStack React Query (https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/query-cancellation) explains how the `queryFn` property can receive an object with a `signal` property, which can be used to cancel a query, like in this example.

```
const query = useQuery({
  queryKey: ['todos'],
  queryFn: async ({ signal }) => {
    const todosResponse = await fetch('/todos', {
      signal,
    })
    const todos = await todosResponse.json()
    const todoDetails = todos.map(async ({ details }) => {
      const response = await fetch(details, {
        signal,
      })
      return response.json()
    })

    return Promise.all(todoDetails)
  },
})
```

The problem is that, with TypeScript, this signal property is type as `AbortSignal | undefined`. With the API that I am using, having to conditionally check if the `signal` is set adds a lot of complexity to the code so it would be very helpful to know under which conditions this `signal` object is not defined. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*react-query v4.29.11*

The `signal` will exist if the [`AbortController`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController) class exists. Let's take a look at the source code:

The `signal` property is added to the query function context by [`addSignalProperty()`](https://github.com/TanStack/query/blob/v4.29.11/packages/query-core/src/query.ts#L377) function, see below:

```
    const addSignalProperty = (object: unknown) => {
      Object.defineProperty(object, 'signal', {
        enumerable: true,
        get: () => {
          if (abortController) {
            this.abortSignalConsumed = true
            return abortController.signal
          }
          return undefined
        },
      })
    }

    addSignalProperty(queryFnContext)
```

The `abortController` is got by [`getAbortController()`](https://github.com/TanStack/query/blob/v4.29.11/packages/query-core/src/utils.ts#L417) function

```
export function getAbortController(): AbortController | undefined {
  if (typeof AbortController === 'function') {
    return new AbortController()
  }
  return
}
```

That's why the TS type of `signal` property is: `AbortSignal | undefined`.

The official documentation also mentions it.

> The `AbortController` API is available in most runtime environments, but if the runtime environment does not support it then the query function will receive `undefined` in its place. You may choose to polyfill the `AbortController` API if you wish, there are several available.

Comment: Great answer! Starting with v5, all supported environments will also have AbortController defined, so the signal will always be there.